# Python asyncio and subprocess_exec(): Get siginfo_t of exited process

Tags: python, unix, asynchronous, signals, python-asyncio

So the Python `asyncio` module provides a nice way to asynchronously interact with the input/output streams of a live process using `subprocess_exec`.  Generally, this is done by setting up a subclass that inherits from `asyncio.SubprocessProtocol`, and writing methods for:

```
def connection_made(self, transport):
  ...

def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
  ...

def process_exited(self):
  ...
```

That last method, `process_exited`, is invoked when the process exits.  Here you can get the return code via the `return_code()` method of the `transport` object.  However, I'd like to be able to get even more specific information about a process that exited abnormally.  I'd like to be able to get the information provided via a `siginfo_t` object that UNIX/Linux/POSIX platforms make available via the `waitid()/waitpid()` family of functions.  The `siginfo_t` struct provides lots of useful information about why the process exited, such as if it was killed by a signal (Segmentation Fault/Aborted, etc.) and other information.

I tried using the Python wrappers in the `os` module to call `os.waitid(...)` in the `process_exited` callback, but it raises a `ChildProcessError` exception, presumably because by the time `process_exited` is invoked, the child process has already exited and therefore `os.waitpid()` won't work.

So is there any way with the `asyncio.SubprocessProtocol` workflow to retrieve the `siginfo_t` from the exited child process?

Comment: About `returncode`: [A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html?highlight=returncode#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process.returncode)